# Is there a formula for the product of elements of the dihedral group of order 8? (Abstract Algebra - Herstein, Ch 2, Example 9)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've just started studying group theory and I've come across this example.

I manage to verify that G is indeed a non-abelian group of order 8 under the composition operation, but I did not manage to obtain a formula in the like of the one suggested at the end of the problem.

Is there even such a formula? If so, could you help me to come up with it?

Thanks in advance and my apologies for anything I might have done wrong, this is my first question here.

[Example 9 - Herstein, Abstract Algebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkljg.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Use $f^2=g^4=e$ and $fg=gf^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. I just don't see how using these relations can be helpful since $f^2$ and $g^4$ are not in G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the notation of your exercise: if $s=0$ then it is obvious that $A: = f^ig^jf^sg^t = f^ig^{j+t}$. Now if $s=1$, in the proof that you posted, the nice formula $gf = fg^{-1}$ is given. Now $A = f^ig^jfg^t = f^i g^{j-1} (gf)g^t = f^ig^{j-1}fg^{t-1}$. Do this again and again: you will end up with $A = f^{i+1}g^{t-j}$. You can give the general formula as $A = f^{i+s}g^{t + (1- 2s)j}$. I hope this answers your question

Comment: Yes, it did answer the question. Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @LucasCruz There is a better way to thank him by accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you for that, I had no idea I had to accept the answer.